# Using typedef with raw pointer vs. shared_ptr

Tags: c++, typedef, shared-ptr

Here's an example of a linked list `Node` struct containing an `int data` and a `NodePtr next`.

My idea is to use a `typedef` for the `NodePtr` because I want to experiment with a raw pointer vs. a shared_ptr. Also, to keep it simple, I want to be able to change just a single line to go from one to the other.

With raw pointers, the following code compiles just fine.

```
typedef struct Node* NodePtr;
struct Node {
   int data;
   NodePtr next;
};
```

But if I simply change the typedef to a shared_ptr, I get compilation errors.

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Node> NodePtr;
struct Node {
   int data;
   NodePtr next;
};

error: ‘Node’ was not declared in this scope
error: template argument 1 is invalid
```

I can fix this by making a forward declaration of `Node`. However, the double definitions of `Node` look a bit ugly to me.

```
struct Node;
typedef std::shared_ptr<Node> NodePtr;
struct Node {
   int data;
   NodePtr next;
};
```

So, why does the first `typedef` work fine but the second one does not?
And, is it possible to `typedef shared_ptr`s without using a forward declaration?

Comment: By the way, a `shared_ptr` is in all probability the wrong smart pointer here. Do you really want shared ownership? Isn’t `unique_ptr` more likely, given the structure?

Comment: Thanks, yes, shared_ptr is not what's needed for this example. 
I am simply experimenting with how you'd replace a raw pointer with a smart pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, why does the first `typedef` work fine but the second one does not?

Because your first `typedef` forward-declares `Node`:

```
typedef struct Node* NodePtr;
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You could do the same in the second `typedef`:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<struct Node> NodePtr;
```

If you want to avoid it, declare the typedef *inside* the structure:

```
struct Node {
    typedef Node* ptr; // no need for `struct`!
    // or `typedef std::shared_ptr<Node> ptr;`
    int data;
    ptr next;
};
```

Also, since this is C++11, you can use `using` instead of `typedef`:

```
using ptr = Node*; // vs. `using ptr = std::shared_ptr<Node>`
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand it better now.
If I move the `typedef` inside the struct, it will only be visible in that scope. But since I want `NodePtr` to be visible in other places, I would prefer the `typedef` to be outside.

Comment: @user2602740 You can always do `Node::ptr` from the outside.